# UserAgent cannot be changed from UserDefaults only iOS 17 Device using Xcode 15

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, user-agent

I want to custom UserAgent(UA) in UIWebView  using registerDefaults method of NSUserDefaults

```
    NSString *userAgent = @"test user agent";
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dict];
```

**[test result]**

> iOS 17.0 > UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_0 like Mac
> OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
>
> iOS 16.4 > UserAgent: test user agent
> iOS 15.0 > UserAgent: test
> user agent

UserAgent cannot be changed from UserDefaults **only iOS 17 Device using Xcode 15**

I know it can be replaced with WKWebView customUserAgent.

```
webview.customUserAgent = "test user agent"
```

But, I want to know how to custom UserAgent(UA) in not WKWebview
but **UIWebView**.

Comment: UIWebView was deprecated 5 years ago. WKWebView has been the preferred option since iOS 8 (9 years ago). For many reasons, you should not be using UIWebView any more.

Comment: I didnt find any solution,,, i think there is no solution,,, :(

Comment: ★★★I find solution!!!! 
This issue is caused by the failure to set up UserAgent in UIWebView from Xcode 15 and iOS 17 versions, requiring a request to switch to WKWebView
everyone can read this Git Issue and relevant Issue : 
1. https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/6a68b0c65d6c2504c8455ce9f88b870fb4d6ed94#diff-cf8c1c0ebdf898376c7a739f7724a4cf1fcd8137d658e57a50ece83c0590d271
2. https://qiita.com/yanamura/items/8828bb885ddc71f7eabdhttps://qiita.com/yanamura/items/8828bb885ddc71f7eabd

Comment: @lxxyeon how did you solve the issue? Your second link doesn’t work anymore. Could paste the solution in here?

Comment: @keeluu Hi:) i added comment already > This issue is caused by the failure to set up UserAgent in UIWebView from Xcode 15 and iOS 17 versions So you have to convert UIWebView to WKWebView :(